# How to find latest version of a document?

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables as tblDocument, tblDocVersions connected using primary key docid as follows:

**tblDocument**:  `docid | title`

**tblVersions**: `id | docid | verion | datecreated | status`

tblVersions could have data as

```
id  + docid + version
----+-------+--------+
1   | 1     | 1
----+-------+---------
2   | 1     | 2
----+-------+---------
3   | 1     | 3
----+-------+---------
4   | 2     | 1
----+-------+---------
5   | 3     | 1
----+-------+---------
6   | 3     | 2
----+-------+---------
```

Now I need to select each individual document with it latest version...

**NOTE:** I need to select the row from `Versions` that correcpond to the latest version number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select max(version), tab1.docid from tblDocument as tab1
inner join tblVersions as tab2 on tab1.docid = tab2.docid 
group by tab1.docid
```

**EDIT**

Not sure but this will work for you

```
select tab1.* from tblDocument as tab1
inner join tblVersions as tab2 on tab1.docid = tab2.docid 
inner join 

  (select max(version) as ver,tab1.docid from tblDocument group by tab1.docid )  d
on d.docid = tab1.docid and  d.ver = tab1.version
```

Comment: The solution looks good, but as mentioned in the question I am nott just interested in the latest version number, but also the relevant row in `tblVersions`.